# Configure kbd and immediately profit of the changes without rebooting

Tags: linux, debian, console, clock

I want to disable consoleblank and activates console clock `vcstime` which are obviously managed by `kbd` on my Debian 6.
So I've changed the following in `/etc/kbd/config` file:

- POWERDOWN_TIME=1
- BLANK_TIME=1
- DO_VCSTIME=yes

But theses settings aren't taken into account (knows it because the clock doesn't appears) after a:

```
# /etc/init.d/kbd restart
Setting console screen modes.
Skipping font and keymap setup (handled by console-setup).
# /etc/init.d/console-setup restart
```

What is the correct way of changing `kbd` configuration and activates it without rebooting?

Edit: Indicates version used :

- Debian 6 "Squeeze" v6.0.6
- `kbd` package v1.15.2-2
- `console-setup` package v1.68+squeeze2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `setup()` function in `/etc/init.d/kbd`.  It does a number of checks, like requiring that you're running `/etc/init.d/kbd restart` inside a virtual console before it starts `vcstime`.  My guess is that you're starting it from within an xterm, via ssh, in screen, or something similar so it doesn't have direct access to your console.

Comment: You're right, I was using a remote computer to restart `kbd`: When doing it from a virtual console, clock appeared and consoleblanking stopped. I'll accept this answer because it fixed my issues.

Comment: On a side note: I can't disable the clock. Reactivating the _consoleblank_ (by editing `/etc/kbd/config`) and restarting `kbd` works but not the `vcstime`. When restarting `kbd` (even tryed restarting `console-setup`) the clock does disappear but only until I run another command (any command: eg. `ls`), then the clock is again shown.

Comment: `sudo killall vcstime` will probably fix it.

Comment: You were right: several `vcstime` processes were running. Killing them made the clock stopped, then restarting `kbd` cleared it from console. Thanks again :)