# How to disable fade to black for the fullscreen console

Tags: debian, console, power-management

After a while of inactivity the fullscreen console fades to black until I press a key.
I want to disable the fade to black on my fullscreen console running in a VirtualBox.

I'm running Debian 8 Jessie and I'm not using a window manager.

Comment: Have you looked at http://superuser.com/questions/837058/stop-screensaver-and-lock-session-on-debian-by-command-line ?

Comment: Yes, I have no window manager and I don't want one.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55242/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution part 1: Configure kbd

Debian uses `kbd`, search for `BLANK_TIME` in `/etc/kbd/config`:

```
# screen blanking timeout.  monitor remains on, but the screen is cleared to
# range: 0-60 min (0==never)  kernels I've looked at default to 10 minutes.
# (see linux/drivers/char/console.c)
BLANK_TIME=30
```

Changing `BLANK_TIME=0` will disable blanking, see [Change Linux console screen blanking behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior/935833#935833).

### Problem: Bug in Jessie

If this doesn't work, you're probably affected by [bug #771161](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771161) /  [bug #750631](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=750631) in Jessie.

### Solution part 2: Workaround for systemd

Edit `/etc/init.d/kbd` and change line 222 from

```
setterm $setterm_args
```

to

```
TERM=linux setterm > /dev/tty1 $setterm_args
```

Technical details can be found in the bugreport above.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Bug #771161, see my updated answer.

Comment: I was affected by the bug.